# How can I scrap the data from a web-site? (scraper crate)

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a task to extract the price data from a website. And the problem is about parsing the prices. When I parse it the only thing I see is "0 ₽". But when I have a page opened and I'm inspecting it I can see the standard price which I need to get. I'll paste some screenshots and code samples below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm3F2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hat1S.jpg

Tried to use async completion with tokio crate.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn go_smoke_parse() -> () {
    let request = reqwest::get("https://gosmoke.ru/zhidkosti")
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .await
        .unwrap();
    let document = scraper::Html::parse_document(&request);
    let names_selector = scraper::Selector::parse("div.caption-title>a")
        .unwrap();
    let price_selector = scraper::Selector::parse("div.price>span")
        .unwrap();
    let names = document
        .select(&names_selector)
        .map(|title| title.inner_html());
    let prices = document
        .select(&price_selector)
        .map(|price| price.inner_html());
    for elements in names {
        println!("{}", elements)
    }
    for price in prices {
        println!("{}", price.trim())
    }
}
```

Tried to use reqwest builder.

```
fn price_parse() -> () {
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::builder()
        .timeout(Duration::from_secs(10))
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let request = client.get("https://gosmoke.ru/zhidkosti")
        .send()
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .unwrap();
    let document = scraper::Html::parse_document(&request);
    let price_selector = scraper::Selector::parse("div.price>span")
        .unwrap();
    let prices = document
        .select(&price_selector)
        .map(|price| price.inner_html());
    for price in prices {
        println!("{}", price.trim())
    }
}
```

I thought I can add a delay to url-request so when it parses it the price will change to regular.

Comment: Your web page probably includes some javascript that changes the page dynamically to overwrite the 0 with the real value, probably by retrieving the values in JSON or XML through another request → you need to find out what that other request is and retrieve the data the same way.

Comment: You might consider https://docs.rs/headless_chrome/latest/headless_chrome/

Comment: @BallpointBen thanks! Had to spent some time but I've solved this case. To be honest, when I've first seen this library I couldn't believe it can help me. It works like a charm now.